# Call Parent Pop-Up Jquery function from A child Pop-Up?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bpopup

I have a scenario:  (A) Parent Page => (B) Child Pop-up => (C)Child Pop-Up.

I am using `window.parent.FunctionName();` for calling jquery's function from B to A, It's working fine.

But I am unable to call a function from C which is defined on B. I am using bpopup with MVC 3.

Comment: Have you tried window.opener.function_on_B() on popup C?

Comment: cubuzoa: Yes I tried but it didn't work. I says `window.opener is null`.

Comment: cubuzoa: I found a solution. I don't know how good it is? but it worked. `window.parent.$("#iframe_B")[0].contentWindow.FunctionName();` .

Comment: you used iframe, have you got iframe on your example?

Comment: Yes. I didn't specify about iframe while asking question. Sorry for this stupidity.

Comment: If you use iframe, all the case changes. You can reach window object by using iframe and then contentWindow